# Twitter typeahead.js / Bloodhound (v 0.10.2): How to update the (local) source dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter, typeahead.js, bloodhound

In the below example, how should you update the (local) "source" after a selection was made ?

The selected value should be deleted from the "source" (and eventually also be re-added, when necessary) so it can't be selected again.

```js
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
    'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
    'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
    'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
    'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

// constructs the suggestion engine
var states = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: $.map(states, function(state) { return { value: state }; })
});

// kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
states.initialize();

$('#input')
    .typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: states.ttAdapter()
    })
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(object, datum) {
        // This is the function that should update the "source" (i.e.: delete the selected value from it)
        update_the_source_with(datum.value);
    });
```

Comment: Remove isn't currently supported. Here's the [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/652) that tracks adding this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve managed to succeed with the current version of Typeahead. The key is not to use Bloodhound#ttAdapter() as the source. Instead, use Bloodhound#get() directly with a custom callback that checks the suggestion against current selections.

Here’s a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/likeuntomurphy/tvp9Q/

```
var selected = [];

var select = function(e, datum, dataset) {
    selected.push(datum.val);
    $("#selected").text(JSON.stringify(selected));
    $("input.typeahead").val("");
}

var filter = function(suggestions) {
    return $.grep(suggestions, function(suggestion) {
        return $.inArray(suggestion.val, selected) === -1;
    });
}

var data = new Bloodhound({
    name: 'animals',
    local: [{ val: 'dog' }, { val: 'pig' }, { val: 'moose' }],
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

data.initialize();

$('input.typeahead').typeahead(null,
    {
        name: 'animals',
        displayKey: 'val',
     /* don't use
        source: data.ttAdapter(), */
        source: function(query, cb) {
            data.get(query, function(suggestions) {
                cb(filter(suggestions));
            });
        },
        templates: {
            empty: '<div class="empty-message">No matches.</div>'
        }
    }
).bind('typeahead:selected', select);
```

If you select “dog”, you’ll see it is no longer available to be selected again. This does not actually remove the selection from the dataset. So if you implement the ability to deselect a selection, all you have to do is remove it from your array of selections — it will automatically appear in the suggestions again after that.